# Trouble getting angular-timer directive to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer

Trying to get a simple timer directive to work on a fitness app, the 3rd line

```
<ion-view view-title="Add/Edit Workout" ng-controller="WorkoutEditsCtrl">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
     <h3><timer /></h3>

        <!-- <h1 class="title">{{workout.name}}</h1> -->

            <button class="button button-icon ion-compose"ng-click="addEx(); startTimer()"></button>

    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
```

It seems to have installed correctly in bower, in my index.html I have this line and it seems fine:

```
<script src="lib/angular-timer/app//js/_timer.js"></script>
```

than in my controller file :

```
var contollers = angular.module('CovalentFitness.controllers', ['timer'])

contollers.controller('WorkoutEditsCtrl', function($scope, $location, $ionicModal, WorkoutServices) {
  //Timer

  // $scope.timerRunning = true;

  // $scope.startTimer = function (){
  //     $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
  //     $scope.timerRunning = true;
  // };

  // $scope.stopTimer = function (){
  //     $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
  //     $scope.timerRunning = false;
  // };

  // $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
  //     console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
  // });
})
```

this has worked before for previous directives I've installed...
this is the error I get

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: I18nServiceProvider <- I18nService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the wrong file. You should include the `angular-timer.js` file that's in the `dist` folder.

```
<script src="lib/angular-timer/dist/angular-timer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, now it just says humanize duration is not defined, so i guess I have to install that too

Comment: Looks like you need momentjs also, in case you don't already have it. https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer#requirements